# Is it right or wrong to use I does in a sentence?

Tags: grammaticality

Is it just wrong to use I does in a sentence or is it okay?

Comment: It would never be correct in any context, according to grammar rules.  The first person pronoun, "I",  is always used with the "do" in a sentence, never with the third person present tense of the verb, "do."

Answer (score 2):

Rules are there to be broken if you know what you're doing, and to be followed to the letter if you don't.

In other words, no, you cannot possibly use *I does* for exactly as long as the question "can I say *I does*" is a question that could possibly cross your mind.

Answer (score 0):

You can't say *I does* instead of *I do*. But one can make up a grammatically-correct sentence in which *I* is followed by *does*:

> "You" refers to a different grammatical person than "I" does.

If not artificially constructed in this way, *I does* is always incorrect.

(The above answer assumes that *does* in the question is the third person singular conjugation of the verb *to do*, and not the plural of the noun *doe* (a deer, a female deer).)

Answer (score 0):

In informal British dialogue, the first person sometimes conjugates like the third person singular in a present progressive tense, reporting past events.

This is part of what has been described on this site as "the historic present".

*There is a loud scream from the neighbours' house, so I goes over to see what is happening, and I does the polite thing of ringing the door bell before entering...*

For a discussion of the historic present see: [Using the present tense in recounting past events](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/323963/using-the-present-tense-in-recounting-past-events)

Comment: "I goes" is non-standard, but perfectly normal in some dialects of English. But it's not a characteristic of the historic present *per se*: that's actually standardly grammatical, "...so I go over and do the polite thing..."

Comment: @AndrewLeach Yes. I was at first minded to mention that it was a feature of dialect, but I couldn't exactly think which dialects. Hence I settled for "informal".  One is tempted to say it is Cockney, but I am not sure. It may be one of those things that is simply non-standard (working-class?) English.